# Failing to update Azure AD group's display name from C# code using MS Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0, group

I am trying to update the `displayName` of an EntraID (Azure AD) group from my C# code.

I have an Azure App registration that has (delegated) permissions for `MS Graph - Group.ReadWrite.All`, and I have applied admin consent on this for my entire tenant.

Using the `Microsoft.Identity.Client`, I can easily run my .NET 6.0 console app and using the `PublicClientApplication`, I can get a valid access token for that scope, for the currently logged in user (interactively - with a standard M365 login prompt dialog). I can also query MS Graph to get me the `Id` of the group I'm interested in - so far, so good.

But the heart of my task - updating the `displayName` of that EntraID group, fails with a **http 403 - forbidden** error - even though my app registration clearly has the `Group.ReadWrite.All` permission, and the access token I get also lists that scope (when I decode it at `https://jwt.ms`).

This is the code to update the display name of my group:

```
public class GroupHandler
{
    private HttpClient _client;

    public GroupHandler(string graphBaseUrl, string accessToken)
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(graphBaseUrl);    // this is https://graph.microsoft.com
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
    }

    public async Task UpdateGroupDisplayName(string groupId, string displayName)
    {
        string requestUrl = $"/v1.0/groups/{groupId}";

        PatchObject patchObj = new PatchObject { displayName = displayName };
        JsonContent content = JsonContent.Create(patchObj, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = await _client.PatchAsync(requestUrl, content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Group has been successfully renamed to '{displayName}'");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase}");
        }
    }
}

// this is the class to hold the new display name, to be serialized to JSON for the PATCH call
public class PatchObject
{
    public string displayName { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas? I'm a bit at a loss, since my app registration *has* the necessary permission, they have admin consent, the token also shows that scope - so why would it still fail?

Comment: Could you please try running the same query in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) by granting `Group.ReadWrite.All` permission and check if it's working or not?

Comment: I would expect that some actions require a user to be in a specific role like Group Administrator, Global Administrator, etc., but no remarks in the doc.

Answer (score 2):

> I agree with *@user2250152*, the **signed-in** user should have extra
> role like **Groups Administrator** along with `Group.ReadWrite.All`
> **delegated** permission while using interactive flows.

I have one Azure AD group named **`SriGroup`** in my tenant with below properties:

[image]

When I tried to rename this group by signing in with user having no directory roles and granting **only** `Group.ReadWrite.All` **delegated** permission in application, I too got **same error** as below:

**Sample code:**

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

var scopes = new[] { "Group.ReadWrite.All" };

var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientId = "appId";

var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
{
    TenantId = tenantId,
    ClientId = clientId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
};

var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);

var requestBody = new Group
{
    DisplayName = "Sri Group Nov",
};

try
{
    await graphClient.Groups["groupId"].PatchAsync(requestBody);
    Console.WriteLine($"Group has been successfully renamed");

}

catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
    throw;
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, I assigned **Groups Administrator** role to that user in my tenant like this:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Microsoft Entra ID -> Roles and administrators -> All roles -> Select Groups Administrator -> Add assignments*

[image]

When I ran the code again by signing in with user having *Groups Administrator* role, I got the **response** like this:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

var scopes = new[] { "Group.ReadWrite.All" };

var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientId = "appId";

var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
{
    TenantId = tenantId,
    ClientId = clientId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
};

var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);

var requestBody = new Group
{
    DisplayName = "Sri Group Nov",
};

try
{
    await graphClient.Groups["groupId"].PatchAsync(requestBody);
    Console.WriteLine($"Group has been successfully renamed");

}

catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
    throw;
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where group name **updated** successfully as below:

[image]

Alternatively, you can also make use of **client credentials** flow by granting `Group.ReadWrite.All` permission of **Application** type that does not require any extra roles.